# Basic empty file builder for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, templates, npm, boilerplate

Perhaps I'm missing something about Node, but what I'm hoping to do is very very simple.

Recently I've been creating a lot of small projects to test small node modules individually before trying to use them in a larger complex project.

I just want to automate generating a blank index.html and main.js file with the appropriate empty tags. I suppose I could make some git repos and just pull those every time, but that seems like overkill. Or I could just create a command to copy files from some other directory to the current one.

But ideally - I could install "npm boiler" or something, then just run "boiler static-html" and have those files plop into the root directory.

I'm running a git bash shell in Windows btw, because work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a perfect solution, but Yeoman sort of handles what I'm after. A simplified version of Yeoman would be ideal.